# Predict customers next month purchase

Tags: time-series, regression, data-science, prediction

I am new to machine learning. So apologize in advance if the question is not smart enough.

I have just completed learning linear regression. Now I want to apply my skill on a sample e-commerce data. For example, I have a purchase history of a customer on a specific site which is as follows:

```
Date          product     amount
2016-12-01     A           300
2016-16-01     B           500
2016-01-02     C           400
..............................
..............................
```

Now I can predict what can be his purchase on month of December by fitting a time series regression model.

But now I have given purchase histry of multiple customers. With additional customerId column. How can I model it to predict purchase amount for each customer for month of December? Actually it does not sound smart to make N model for N individual customer.

Any clue or learning material will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to train N models for N customer if you want to predict a weekly/monthly purchase per customer.

However, if you generally want to know how much your customers buy in total, then add up the shopping values of all customers and create a model to predict the total purchase of all customers.